# Getting not persistent messages from nats.io server

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, nats.io

My question is simple:
Now this code sends empty message to subject `chan.01.msg` and gets message that is being currently broadcasted or prints `nats: timeout`. Altogether this request message is also shown (something like: `Received a message on chan.01.msg _INBOX.<hash_my>.<salt_up>: b''`) on subject and is not desirable there. I do filter it in callback, but I really feel that it's kinda wrong way to do it.
Can I just pull messages with desired subject?

```
async def msgcb(msg):
    """
    Message callback function
    """
    subject = msg.subject
    reply = msg.reply
    data = msg.data
    if len(data) > 0:
        print(f"Received a message on {subject} {reply}: {data}")

logging.debug("Prepare to subscribe")
sub = await nc.subscribe(subject="chan.01.msg", cb=msgcb)

logging.debug("loop process messages on subject")
while True:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    try:
        resp = await nc.request('chan.01.msg')
        print(resp)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: as @wallyqs said, this is the expected behaviour because you're subscribing to the same subject you're subscribing. You could use the `no_echo` option but I don't understand what is your expectation

Comment: well in short I don't really get necessity of `request` if I want to get all messages from particular subject.
It is probably good for debug to see who's pulling what, but spamming empty pull messages in production looks a bit excessive to me. 
`no_echo` - noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subscribing to the same subject where you are publishing so naturally would get the message when sending a request.  To avoid receiving messages the same client produces you can use the no_echo option on connect.